# Show using the epsilon delta definition that this function is discontinuous at 1

Tags: analysis, continuity

The function to be studied is the following one:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 x^2 &\text{ when } x \neq 0\\
 1 &\text{ when } x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Show that $f(x)$ is discontinuous at x=0.
How do I prove this strictly from the epsilon delta definition?
I believe that this means that there exists an epsilon such that 
$$
|f(x)-1|< \epsilon,
$$
where there is no such delta for which 
$$
|x-0|< \delta.
$$But I'm unsure how to continue using the definition to prove this.

I have solved this question, taking x = Min{1/2, δ}

Comment: Take $\epsilon=1/2$ and see what happens.

Comment: What does "x =/=0" mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [proving continuity using epsilon delta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2594536/proving-continuity-using-epsilon-delta)

Comment: It means $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Asserting that $f$ is continuous at $0$ means that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $\lvert x\rvert<\delta\implies\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(0)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon$. Therefore, asserting that $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ means that there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for every $\delta>0$, there is a number $x$ such that $\lvert x\rvert<\delta$ and that $\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(0)\bigr\rvert\geqslant\varepsilon$. Take $\varepsilon=\frac12$ and prove that, indeed, for every $\delta>0$, there is a number $x$ such that $\lvert x\rvert<\delta$ and $\bigl\lvert f(x)-1\bigr\rvert\geqslant\varepsilon$.

Comment: is x = /2 likely to work, its clear that then |x| < , could I then impose a condition on , so that I would have x^2 < 1/2? Would that then leave me with |x^2 - 1| > 1/2 if that condition was the case?

Comment: You **can't** impose any condition on $\delta$. Did you not read what I wrote? It says “for every $\delta>0$”.

Comment: oh my mistake, the only condition I'm allowed to have is that  > 0

Comment: I have to find a general x for every ?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by “general”, but, yes, you have to find a $x$ for each $\delta>0$.